# Cholesky decomposition for a Hermitian matrix in SDP

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, hermitian-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

I have a variable matrix $W$ that is Hermitian and is used in two SDP problems.

- Problem 1 has constraints that depend on the real diagonal elements of $W$.

Example of the constraint is $W_{ii}+x_{ij}+y_{ij}=0$ Where $W_{ii}$ is a real diagonal element of the Hermitian $W$ matrix.

- Problem 2 has constraints that depend on the complex off-diagonal elements of $W$.

Examples of these constraints are $real(W_{ij})+x_{ij}+y_{ij}=0$ and $imag(W_{ij})+x_{ij}+y_{ij}=0$ Where $W_{ij}$ is a complex off-diagonal element of the Hermitian $W$ matrix.

Where $i,j \in l, \forall l \in NT$ where $NT$ is the number of branches (Branch $l$ connects nodes $i$ and $j$).
Note that in both cases, $x$ and $y$ are decision variables that aren't elements of a matrix variable.

For a large scale problem with thousands of such constraints (e.g $NT$=5000), Which problem would be easier to solve and why? Would Cholesky decomposition be cheaper for the first problem due to the dependency on the real diagonal elements of $W$?

Comment: Why don't you show the SDPs?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have edited the problem to make it clearer. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It still lacks details. Are you sure that in the second problem, the terms $x_i$ and $y_j$ are independent of $j$ and that both $x_i$ and $y_i$ are involved in the constraints for the real and the imaginary part of the off-diagonal elements? I mean you are asking us to tell which problem is simpler without saying much about the problems. The complexity depends on the total number of variables and constraints.

Comment: @KBS I have edited the problem. I'm not sure if it is clear enough for you. What I'm trying to know is whether the dependence on diagonal elements of the hermitian matrix $W$ is more computationally efficient than using off-diagonal elements of the $W$ matrix when solving a SDP -based optimization problem? Please let me know how I can make things clearer for you if needed? Thank you.

Comment: It does not matter which elements you consider in the matrix. What matters is the size of the constraints and the number of decision variables.